# passing objects to modal dialog in AngularJS/bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass an object into a modal dialog in a bootstrap/angularJS using the code below.  I did this in the style of the answer given at [AngularJS UI Bootstrap modal is unable to perform functions from scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120342/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-modal-is-unable-to-perform-functions-from-scope).  When the modal form is supposed to open from a call to editGroup(), I get the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: selGroupProvider <- selGroup

```
var EditGroupModalController = function ($scope, $modalInstance, selGroup) {        
        $scope.user = $sessionStorage.user;
        $scope.selGroup = selGroup;

        $scope.closeModal = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
    };

    $scope.editGroup = function (selGroup) { // "selGroup" receives the current Group object from $scope.groupList[]
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/administration/advanced/editgroup.html',
            controller:  ['$scope', '$modalInstance','$modal','$sessionStorage','advancedService','selGroup', EditGroupModalController],
            size: 'lg',
            windowTemplateUrl:'app/views/partials/modaltemplatedraggable.html',
            backdrop:'static',
            resolve: {
                item: function () {
                    return selGroup;
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

The official description of this error is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr); however, I do not understand why I am receiving this error.  Any help with this would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your controller's dependencies list doesn't match controller's function definition: in `$modal.open` you've listed six dependencies, while in function only three are present.
2. Dependencies are injected by `resolve` keys - in your case the key is `item`.

Necessary changes to your code in order to make it work:

Replace (1)

```
var EditGroupModalController = function ($scope, $modalInstance, selGroup)
```

with

```
var EditGroupModalController = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $modal, $sessionStorage, advancedService, selGroup)
```

And replace (2)

```
resolve: {
    item: function () {
```

With

```
resolve: {
    selGroup: function () {
```

Comment: Your corrections worked perfectly.  Thank you for the explanation, as well!

Answer (score 0):

You should name the variable in the resolve as 'selGroup' instead of 'item' so that it can be correctly injected.

Also, the names of the declared dependencies should match the function definition. I put together this simple demo.

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('TestController', function($scope, $modal) {
  var sel = {name: "A group"};
  var EditGroupModalController = function($scope, $modalInstance, selGroup) {
    $scope.selGroup = selGroup;
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $modalInstance.close();
    };
  };

  $scope.editGroup = function(selGroup) { // "selGroup" receives the current Group object from $scope.groupList[]
    $modal.open({
      template: '<div>Test {{selGroup.name}}</div>',
      controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'selGroup', EditGroupModalController],
      size: 'lg',
      backdrop: 'static',
      resolve: {
        selGroup: function() {
          return sel;
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ec1PjkDZtf4yqINONnX5?p=preview